# why are my custom tasks not executed with android build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Following are the two tasks I have written to copy my **`apk`** file from one location to the other

```
verifyTargetPath { doLast { if (!targetPath.exists()) { throw new GradleException("Target path not valid!")
```

My tasks run fine when I test them using command line but are not executed when I build my project. I am new to android so help here would be appreciated

Comment: verifyTargetPath {
    doLast {
        if (!targetPath.exists()) {
            throw new GradleException("Target path not valid!")

Comment: I want the tasks to be executed along with the build

Comment: Instead of adding comments to your question, could you add all required information to the question itself? Additionally, What are the two tasks that you have written? Why do you need to copy the apk?